# Faking UIView animation with drawRect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I have a `UIView` that draws itself using `-drawRect:` and I want to animate the colors used for the drawing. Basic `UIView` animation stuff doesn’t work for obvious reasons (`drawRect`).

I can’t simply use `CAShapeLayer` to draw and animate the view contents. I’d like to try faking the animation by hand, using a timer or `CADisplayLink` in combination with `setNeedsDisplay`. Is there a reasonably simple way to hide this magic behind the usual `UIView` animation API?

For example, let’s say there’s a `color` property I’d like to animate:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    [customDrawingView setColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}];
```

Is there a way to “intercept” the animation call to read the animation parameters (time, target value) and process them by hand? I don’t want to swizzle `UIView`.

Comment: [CocoaHeads Session: Rob Napier on Animating Custom Layer Properties](http://vimeo.com/44986916)

Comment: Thank you. That’s using `CALayer`s, though? I have existing drawing code that looks hard to refactor into a `CALayer` and I can easily live with a simple animation with just a few steps. That’s why I’d like to try it with the existing `drawRect` implementation.

Comment: Although the longer I keep thinking about it, the more I’m convinced that `CALayer` is the way to go.

Comment: You can do your custom Core Graphics drawing in the layer as well.

Comment: I’ve tried the `CALayer` approach. `CALayer` has no animatable color, so I tried `CAShapeLayer`. But `CAShapeLayer` only supports a single path, and I needed a complex path with different strokes, fills and options. I could draw that in a plain `CALayer`, but then I would have to add the animation support by hand. In the end it was much easier to animate the existing drawing code using `CADisplayLink` and `setNeedsDisplay`. I had to add explicit animated API call (à la `setProperty:duration:`), but I can live with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to do something like you did quite a few times. In general you can create some classes to handle stuff like floating point interpolation or `CGPoint` interpolation... and do it all properly but since the whole drawing already exists there is not much point in it.

So the `UIView` `animateWithDuration` will not work here but you can add your display link and do the interpolation manually. It is best done if no existing code is changed, only add a few methods:

Assuming you currently have something like this:

```
- (void)setColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    _color = color;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Now you can add `setColorAnimated:` and do all the additional functionality:

You need some additional parameters (properties), use what you want:

```
UIColor *_sourceColor;
UIColor *_targetColor;
NSDate *_startDate;
NSDate *_endDate;
CADisplayLink *_displayLink;
```

And the methods:

```
- (void)setColorAnimated:(UIColor *)color {
    _sourceColor = self.color; // set start to current color
    _targetColor = color; // destination color
    _startDate = [NSDate date]; // begins currently, you could add some delay if you wish
    _endDate = [_startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:.3]; // will define animation duration

    [_displayLink invalidate]; // if one already exists
    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(onFrame)]; // create the display link
}
- (UIColor *)interpolatedColor:(UIColor *)sourceColor withColor:(UIColor *)targetColor forScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    // this will interpolate between two colors
    CGFloat r1, g1, b1, a1;
    CGFloat r2, g2, b2, a2;
    [sourceColor getRed:&r1 green:&g1 blue:&b1 alpha:&a1];
    [targetColor getRed:&r2 green:&g2 blue:&b2 alpha:&a2];

    // do a linear interpolation on RGBA. You can use other
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:r1+(r2-r1)*scale
                           green:g1+(g2-g1)*scale
                            blue:b1+(b2-b1)*scale
                           alpha:a1+(a2-a1)*scale];
}
- (void)onFrame {
    // scale is valid between 0 and 1
    CGFloat scale = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate] / [_endDate timeIntervalSinceDate:_startDate];
    if(scale < .0f) {
        // this can happen if delay is used
        scale = .0f;
    }
    else if(scale > 1.0f)
    {
        // end animation
        scale = 1.0f;
        [_displayLink invalidate];
        _displayLink = nil;
    }
    [self setColor:[self interpolatedColor:_sourceColor withColor:_targetColor forScale:scale]];
}
```

Comment: The `CALayer` code turned out to be a pain in the ass, so I ended up doing the animation by hand as suggested here. I’m still curious if it’s possible to hide the implementation behind the implicit `UIView` animation API.

Comment: Could be but I kind of doubt it. What you would need to get from the animation itself would be the "interpolator", the value ranging from 0 to 1. But it is hard to say what Apple did in the background, is there a class containing the animation parameters such as source and target or the views contain them their self. Anyway this method is useless on anything beyond the simplest of animations. Unless you need this procedure on more then a few places I think it is not even worth the time to research.

Comment: I’d be happy just to get the target value and duration.

Comment: If that is for a specific view simply subclass it and override the animateWithDuration methods.. Then call the same method I posted in this answer I guess.

Comment: D’oh, that didn’t occur to me, thanks. The catch is that the implicit animation API may be called somewhere higher up the view hierarchy, ie. in the view’s superview. It could be worked around I guess, but I would not be able to keep the magic encapsulated in the class that needs it. It’s probably not worth the hassle. Thanks again!

Comment: You could override it through category but the issue is you can not call the original method from it. Next thing you could do is create a new (some other name) similar method for the animation in the category then in it implement your custom logic plus calling the original method. Then what you would need to do is search through your project and replace all your calls to this methods with the new methods.

Answer (score -1):

Animated (Fade in) new frame created via drawRect

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CABasicAnimation *animation;
    animation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    [animation setDuration:0.5];
    [[self layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];

   .. your stuff here

}
```